# what is the pytorch's view equivalence with tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, torch

```
l_conv7 = self.loc_conv7(conv7_feats)  # (N, 24, 19, 19)
l_conv7 = l_conv7.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous()  # (N, 19, 19, 24)
l_conv7 = l_conv7.view(batch_size, -1, 4)  # (N, 2166, 4), there are a total 2116 boxes on this feature map
```

what is the equivalence with torch's view in TensorFlow? 
how to change the l_conv7.view in TensorFlow 2.0?

Comment: you can use `tf.reshape()`. More specifically, use `l_conv7 = tf.reshape(l_conv7, new_shape)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
l_conv7.reshape(batch_size, -1, 4)
```